# CSS/tables: parallel two columns for different languages?

Tags: html, css, tabular

I'm trying to create a page that has the Czech translation of a text running in parallel with the original English text. I've got the two texts in a nearly finished state. But I'm really not sure how to put them side by side, so that they run in parallel. (I think it would be too much to insist that each *paragraph* begin at the same horizontal location in both languages, but I do think it's a good idea to do it for each of the thirteen *sections*.)

Here is the Czech text: http://www.dinkypage.com/124733

Here is the English text: http://www.dinkypage.com/137154

I've received some suggestions about using tables, but I have no idea how that might work. I'd definitely appreciate any help.

Comment: There is no "nice" way to do it (it's a rather complex typesetting problem); obviously you can align everything with a table, ugly as it may be.

Comment: You can take inspiration from the "Proofread" pane on Duolingo.com, e.g. https://www.duolingo.com/translation/9f949503e613b7fe5d47d222b078d7c3. They solved the problem of selecting multiple paragraphs of text in one language. AFIK, their solution uses JavaScript: it measures the paragraphs and then adds padding. I recommend using the table, it is the simplest way and it is also what hunalign's output looks like (http://mokk.bme.hu/resources/hunalign/).

Answer (score 3):

I have created a simple `table` structure as example.
You can use CSS to style the table.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/UU2AX/

Comment: I've been told in here before never to use tables, and that it constitutes a mortal sin in websites. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is wrong. Tables should only be used for tabular data and when it's necessary. In your case, there's nothing wrong with using tables. Now, if you were building a whole website in tables, you'd get told off by a few people here :p

Comment: I'm really not sure how to get this to work with tables. I've now got the English text in a nearly finished state (linked in the edited question). Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a table row (or CSS div, or whatever), running across the whole page, for each page/paragraph that you wish to be aligned.  This would force shorter language to be padded with space at the end so that the next page/paragraph starts off in the right place.

Comment: Would this make it impossible to select only one side or the other (for purposes of copy/paste)?

Comment: As long as each paragraph/page is in its own DIV (or table cell) then yes.

Comment: OK, I've started messing around with it, but I really don't know how to do it.