# CSS: parallel two columns for different languages?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS/tables: parallel two columns for different languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254867/css-tables-parallel-two-columns-for-different-languages)

I'm trying to create a page that has the Czech translation of a text running in parallel with the original English text. So far, I've got the Czech part more-or-less finished. But I'm really not sure how to work in the English text, so that it runs in parallel. (I think it would be too much to insist that each *paragraph* begin at the same horizontal location in both languages, but I do think it's a good idea to do it for each *chapter*.)

Here is how things look currently: http://www.dinkypage.com/124733

Here is Wikisource's version of the English text: http://tinyurl.com/d9ajujs

Any ideas? Thanks, and I apologize if this is too uninformed a question for this forum.

Comment: This site is for requesting reviews of your (working) code, not for asking how-do-I questions. The latter is what Stack Overflow is for. I've now migrated this question there.

Comment: naházet do tabulky jak radí palacsint, nebo vždycky dva divy vedle sebe(float: left) se stejnou šířkou a obalené dalším divem pro zarovnání následujícího textu... doufám že jsem se s tou češtinou nesekl :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use an HTML table since it's tabular data and create a separate row with two cells for every paragraph. From [Wikipedia, Tableless web design, The use of tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tableless_web_design#The_use_of_tables):

> On the one hand, because of the term "tableless web design", some have
>   interpreted this design strategy as an unconditional repudiation of
>   all tables in web design. This has caused some to avoid tables even
>   when tables are appropriate. Using divisions to simulate a table for
>   the display of tabular data is as much a design flaw as using tables
>   to control graphic and page layout.

Comment: I'd like to, but I really don't know how to combine tables with CSS to produce the desired effect.

Comment: I mean create a table with two columns and as many rows as many paragraphs you have.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I honestly don't know how to do that with the texts I have. I've recently updated my original question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254867/css-tables-parallel-two-columns-for-different-languages